# Is there a `in` like statement for a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I can easily check whether each is equal to a number:

```
In [20]: s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])                                                                                                                

In [21]: s == 1
Out[21]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
```

My problem is, is there a function like `s._in([1, 2])` and output something like

```
0     True
1     True
2     False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is called `isin`.  Do `s.isin([1, 2])`.